# Call the stored procedure with multiple SQL statements such that either both of the SQL statements should executed or none of them

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[spCreation]
(
    @ProgramId nvarchar(20), @S_26 int = 0, @S_28 int = 0, @S_30 int = 0,
    @S_32 int = 0, @S_34 int = 0, @S_36 int = 0, @S_38 int = 0,
    @S_40 int = 0, @S_42 int = 0, @S_44 int = 0, @S_46 int = 0, @S_48 int = 0
)
AS
BEGIN
    insert into tblCreation (ProgramId, S_26, S_28, S_30, S_32, S_34, S_36, S_38, S_40, S_42, S_44, S_46, S_48, Quantity)
    values(@ProgramId, @S_26, @S_28, @S_30, @S_32, @S_34, @S_36, @S_38, @S_40, @S_42, @S_44, @S_46, @S_48,
@S_26+@S_28+@S_30+@S_32+@S_34+@S_36+@S_38+@S_40+@S_42+@S_44+@S_46+@S_48)

    update tblProgramme 
    set ProgramStatus = 'In Process' 
    where ProgramId = @ProgramId
END
```

This is my stored procedure. And I will call that stored procedure in ado.net.
My question is that
What will happen if the table name or column name of second sql statemeny will change in future.will it through exception or it will execute only first statement.

Comment: So you need to use a transaction?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and rename **everything**.

Comment: Which kind of error do you expect to happen in this code?

Comment: If the table/column name changes later, and the second statement is not modified accordingly, then it will throw an exception. Why would you change the table/column name later without modifying the stored procedure as well?

Comment: Then can I use transaction for both the statement in the store procedure..If yes.then please give me syntax according to my stored procedure.Thanks all of you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those column names don't look very friendly, hopefully they have a specific meaning to your project.

What you need is a transaction, I just put this together quickly:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[spCreation]
(
@ProgramId nvarchar(20), @S_26 int = 0, @S_28 int = 0, @S_30 int = 0,
@S_32 int = 0, @S_34 int = 0, @S_36 int = 0, @S_38 int = 0,
@S_40 int = 0, @S_42 int = 0, @S_44 int = 0, @S_46 int = 0, @S_48 int = 0
)
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN TRAN

insert into tblCreation (ProgramId, S_26, S_28, S_30, S_32, S_34, S_36, S_38, S_40, S_42, S_44, S_46, S_48, Quantity) values(@ProgramId, @S_26, @S_28, @S_30, @S_32, @S_34, @S_36, @S_38, @S_40, @S_42, @S_44, @S_46, @S_48, @S_26+@S_28+@S_30+@S_32+@S_34+@S_36+@S_38+@S_40+@S_42+@S_44+@S_46+@S_48)

update tblProgramme 
set ProgramStatus = 'In Process' 
where ProgramId = @ProgramId

IF @@ERROR <> 0 BEGIN 
    ROLLBACK TRAN 
    return 0 
END 

COMMIT TRAN
END 
GO
```

Some further reading:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx

Comment: After reading your update. Changing the update statement itself will not cause an exception in your program. Both should execute as long as the table has been modified. You will need to reflect those changes in other areas of code that may use it.

Comment: Thanks MrSmith sir.I got what i wanted.